# Is it possible for a ML model to perform worse than random classification?

Tags: machine-learning

I implemented different machine learning algorithms on a matrix with binary data to predict a univariate target with two classes.

- random forest (accuracy = 62.01)
- Neural Network(acc= 58.9)
- svm-radial kernel (accuracy = 58.02)
- linear discriminant analysis(accuracy = 57.9)
- logistic regression(accuracy = 57.6).

My baseline accuracy is 52.55. But in case of Naive Bayes in same setting gives only 48.5 accuracy that identifies only one class in y. predict.

Is it possible for a machine learning model to behave worse than a random classification?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible.

Just means the model is adjusting to noise, so it's valuing the "wrong" features.

As an analogy, if you were randomly guessing basketball game outcomes, you'd probably perform better than someone who thinks less points is better and is guessing based on previous games' scores

Comment: Can I report NaiveBayes model result along with other models result? I have to report in my Masters thesis?

Comment: Well, you definitely CAN. This only means that a Naive Bayes model wasn't suited for your problem. Don't know if you should, though. That context is all you!

Comment: Naive Bayes is predicting y.pred as one class. This is something that indicates that the model is biased towards one  class. I fail to understand this behavior. Although my classes are balanced.

Comment: Did you change any parameters for the Naive Bayes model? In what language did you write the script?

Comment: No I have not changed parameters for Naive Nayes. I have written scripts in R

Comment: If you used the same data and there are no parameters, to me it just means that Naive Bayes was not suited for your data, not that there was anything wrong with your modeling technique or data. Especially considering you had 'normal' results with other models

Answer (score 2):

Your model can be worse than random, for example, if some fundamental assumptions are violated, in an imbalanced setting when your using accuracy as your baseline or you have noisy data etc.

However, in a binary setting, if your classes are perfectly balanced and if your classifier is consistently making false predictions (not due to randomness), you can always adjust the model to be better than random by predicting the exact opposite of your model.

Comment: My classes are balanced, I have not removed collinearity in features in every model, so I have kept the basic framework same for all models but for  Naive Bayes I get worst results. Here is another reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211157/naivebayes-classifer-in-r-predicting-only-one-class

Answer (score 2):

Well, absolutely. I had the same issue recently (and ended up here). So I just simulated a dataset and an independant label ([full article here](https://www.thekerneltrip.com/statistics/what-to-expect-from-a-model-when-there-is-nothing-to-learn/))

Basically, when there is nothing to learn, your model will produce predictions uncorrelated to the label. In turn, these predictions (when repeated many times) show an interesting distribution of the error rate (evaluated on a validation set or using cross validation).

However, in your case, I am quite surprised that one specific model does not work correctly, when the others seem to show relevant predictions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. In my case I was doing classification and trained on 64 indices then at test I had a different set of indices 16. This happens because the task is transfer learning. So I should have adapted at test time instead of using the model as is.

The issue is a little more subtle than that and some discussion and plots can be seen here: https://github.com/WangYueFt/rfs/issues/33 but it is possible.